How do i make an indentation onto an object using another object as a projection?
I want to use  the selected object to make an indentation (that is symmetric on the z axis) of equal depth to both sides of the big rim object.
Would the knife tool be appropriate? I already used the boolean modifier to make a hole in the main object (called big rim). I want to make an indentation in big rim that is the size of hole rim (selected object).
For reference, I am trying to make a rubber gym plate.
(I have seen some other tutorials that use the insert faces command in edit mode to accomplish something like that, but I don't think it's the best option).

^ that is the image I am attempting to achieve. You can see there are indendations of slightly smaller circles and one circle is punched through the center.

Hello have you looked into the Knife Project Tool? Maybe show a picture of the object you are trying to achieve?

I added in an image of what I'd like to achieve. I have attempted to use the knife project tool (but had some issues with this error "No other selected objects have wire or boundary edges to use for projection"). I do not want an extraction that cuts a hole through the topology, but an indentation.

@mike Why do you think the Inset tool (inset, not insert) is not the best option? The real plate is made out of a single piece (apart from the metal ring in the hole), and doing this indentation is one of the easiest things to do with the Inset tool. Projection or using the Knife is unnecessarily complicated for this stuff. I also do not understand your base parts. Why does "big rim" have a hole that is too large and "hole rim" has the smaller hole? "Big rim" needs the hole in the final size, then you make an indented ring with some offset from the outer boundary and the inner hole.

Yes you don't need the Knife Project Tool, you can do it with some extrusions

I would anyway start this completely new. How did you create this "big rim" and "hole rim" with the messed up geometry like triangles (that change direction) or the non-uniform faces inside the hole?

gordon, i'll tell you. it was through making a 32 vertice circle and then applying a decimate modifer to reduce the vertices and then extruding it.
